# Powershell - Loop Install of Available Software Updates (SCCM)

Tags: windows, powershell, sccm

I have the below script which I am using to run on critical desktop clients to install all available updates (quarterly) that have been deployed by SCCM.

As some deployed updates only become available when other dependent updates have been installed the script is stopping before the reboot.

I ideally want it to loop and continue to install all available updates until all have installed and then proceed to automatically reboot.

Any ideas?

```
    Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore, PresentationFramework

switch (
  [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show(
    'This action will download and install critical Microsoft updates and may invoke an automatic reboot. Do you want to continue?',
    'WARNING',
    'YesNo',
    'Warning'
  )
) {
 'Yes' 
 {
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\CCM\ClientUX\scclient.exe" "softwarecenter:Page=InstallationStatus"
$installUpdateParam = @{
        NameSpace = 'root/ccm/ClientSDK'
        ClassName = 'CCM_SoftwareUpdatesManager'
        MethodName = 'InstallUpdates'
    }

    $getUpdateParam = @{            
        NameSpace = 'root/ccm/ClientSDK'
        ClassName = 'CCM_SoftwareUpdate'
        Filter = 'EvaluationState < 8'
    }       

    [ciminstance[]]$updates = Get-CimInstance @getUpdateParam
    
    if ($updates) {
        Invoke-CimMethod @installUpdateParam  -Arguments @{ CCMUpdates = $updates } 
        
        while(Get-CimInstance @getUpdateParam){
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
        }
    }

    $rebootPending = Invoke-CimMethod -Namespace root/ccm/ClientSDK -ClassName CCM_ClientUtilities -MethodName DetermineIfRebootPending
    if ($rebootPending.RebootPending){
        Invoke-CimMethod -Namespace root/ccm/ClientSDK -ClassName CCM_ClientUtilities -MethodName RestartComputer
    }
    'No' 
    #  Exit-PSSession
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may loop indefinitely to start the process and stop only when `$updates` is `$null` or empty.

```
    while($true) {
      Start-Process ...

      [ciminstance[]]$updates = Get-CimInstance @getUpdateParam
    
      if ($updates) {
          Invoke-CimMethod @installUpdateParam  -Arguments @{ CCMUpdates = $updates } 
        
          while(Get-CimInstance @getUpdateParam){
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
          }
      }
      else {
        break;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the response! Apologies, new to the forum, and am a powershell amateur, I am struggling to modify the script based on your advice..

Comment: Test it. `if ($updates)` is a shortcut. Maybe `if($null -ne $updates -and $updates.Length -gt 0)` may be better. And you should probably add a `try { } catch { }` block to handle errors and exit the loop gracefully. Else this main run indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks, I have editied and am testing. Am getting a "missing closing } in statement block" error at lines 10 and 12. Think adding the while($true) is affecting the switch statement above?

Comment: You have to close properly blocks. Review carefully { } blocks. It is just a syntax issue here.